# Inpaint an image matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, interpolation, pixel

[image: test image]

I am trying to replace all pixels with certain value in an image with the average values of the neighbors. Can interp2 be useful here? I tried this -

```
I = imread('test_image.JPG');
[r c] = size(I);
class_of_image = class(I);
[xi,yi] = meshgrid(1:0.5:c,1:0.5:r);
I1 = cast(interp2(double(image),xi,yi,'linear'),class_of_image);

[x_z,y_z] = find(I1==0);
I1(x_z,y_z) = I1(x_z-1,y_z)+I1(x_z+1,y_z)+I1(x_z,y_z-1)+I1(x_z,y_z+1);
```

This fails spectacularly with an error message - Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

I realize that the error is in trying to access I1 indices beyond r and c. Is there a generic way to incorporate this in the code?

Please help!

Comment: As a side note, there is a function on the fileexchange, [inpaint_nans](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551-inpaint-nans)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to replace pixels in an image that are at a certain value to be the average of its 4 neighbours, then you don't have to use `interp2`.  It looks like you are doubling the size of the image and then sampling from that image when you're done.

If you want to do what you're asking, you need to use column-major indices to facilitate the vectorized access of pixels.  Specifically, you need to use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to help determine the locations you need to access in your matrix.

However, you will need to account for pixels that go out of bounds.  There are many ways to accommodate this, but what I will implement is known as **zero-padding** where the border pixels are simply set to 0.  I would create a zero-padded image where the top and bottom rows as well as the left and right values are all some sentinel value (like -1), use `find` on this image to find the coordinates then do the inpainting.  Make sure you set the border pixels back to 0 before doing this so that you don't use -1 as part of the inpainting.  You would then crop the border pixels of this new image when you're done to obtain the final output image.

Therefore, if you want to perform your "inpainting" try this instead:

```
% Read in image
I = imread('test_image.JPG');

% Create padded image with border pixels set to -1
Ipad = -ones(size(I) + 2);

% Place image in the middle
Ipad(2:end-1,2:end-1) = I;

% Find zero pixels
[r,c] = find(I == 0);

% Now set border pixels to 0
Ipad(Ipad == -1) = 0;

% Find column major indices for those elements that are 0
% as well as their 4 neighbours
ind = sub2ind(size(I), r, c);
ind_up = sub2ind(size(I), r-1, c);
ind_down = sub2ind(size(I), r+1, c);
ind_left = sub2ind(size(I), r, c-1);
ind_right = sub2ind(size(I), r, c+1);

% Perform the inpainting by averaging
Ipad(ind) = (Ipad(ind_up) + Ipad(ind_down) + Ipad(ind_left) + Ipad(ind_right))/4;

% Store the output in I1 after removing border pixels
I1 = Ipad(2:end-1,2:end-1);
```

---

However, a possibly shorter way to do this even though you would operate on the entire image would be to perform 2D convolution using a 3 x 3 kernel whose elements are 1 in the cardinal directions and ensuring that you divide by 4 to find the average value per location.  After, you would simply copy over those values in the output that are 0 in the original image.  You can use [`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) to do that and make sure you specify the `'same'` flag to ensure that the output size is the same as the input size.  The behaviour of `conv2` when you approach the border elements is to zero-pad, which is what I did already in the first implementation:

```
% Read in image
I = imread('test_image.JPG');

% Specify kernel
kernel = [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0] / 4;

% Perform convolution - make sure you cast image to double
% as convolution in 2D only works for floating-point types
out = conv2(double(I), kernel, 'same');

% Copy over those values from the output that match the value
% to be inpainted for the input.  Also cast back to original 
% data type.
I1 = I;
I1(I == 0) = cast(out(I == 0), class(I));
```

Comment: You have my +1 for convolution. Convolution is always the answer.

Comment: @Suever Certainly is!

Comment: @rayryeng- Thank you very much.I did interp2 only to get the values closer. I tried convolution method - Now if i try to find zeros in I1, it must return null right? That does not seem to be the case.                            find(I1==0) returns  along list of indices.

Comment: @Learner It should. I tried it on a couple of test images.  For example, try `I = reshape(1:25, 5, 5); I([2 6 10 19 24]) = 0;` then use the above code to do the inpainting.  You will see that the final output has no zeroes.  The reason you may **not** be setting all of the zeroes is due to floating-point precision.  Therefore instead of comparing to exactly 0, find the values within some tolerance... perhaps something like 0.5.  I can't tell whether or not it works because you haven't provided a sample image that you want to perform this operation on.

Comment: @rayryeng - I have uploaded a test image on which the method failed.A sufficiently high threshold also does not work. I really appreciate all the help! and i did convert it to gray scale before applying the convolution.

Comment: @Learner OK. I know what's going on.  The reason why it "doesn't" work is because there are neighbouring pixels that surround the 0 pixels that are also 0.  Therefore, if you try to find an average using the neighbours, the output would still be 0.  It's not a problem with the code... it's a problem with your definition of inpainting.  In this case, I would suggest you use this post to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382450/efficient-inpaint-with-neighbouring-pixels/30382717#30382717 - I'm going to mark as a duplicate.